# How to add & remove class by class & id in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

First i want to find which one of menu id has `.show` ex: `<div id="menu1" class="show">Menu 2</div>`.

Ex: If #menu1 have `.show` i want to add `.showcontent` to #content1, if `.show` moved to `#menu2` i have to remove `.showcontent` from `#content1` and add `.showcontent` to `#content2`.

```js
function highlight() {
    var $c = $('.show');
        id = $c.attr('id');
    $('#' + id.replace('menu', 'content')).closest('tr').addClass('showcontent')
}
    highlight()
```

```css
.showcontent {
    color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu0" class="hide">Menu 1</div>
<div id="menu1" class="show">Menu 2</div>
.....
<div id="menu10" class="hide">Menu 10</div>

<!--Content--> 
<table>
<tbody>
<tr><td id="content0">Menu 1 Content</td></tr>
<tr><td id="content1">Menu 2 Content</td></tr>
...
<tr><td id="content10">Menu 10 Content</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Any help highly appreciated because i spend lot of time to do this. Thank you.

Comment: It will be easy If you assign same class to `contentN` and `menuN` ex: `class="N show"` then you can remove class `show` of all elements and toggle ones of same class `N` the class `show`

Comment: you can start with something like this but not sure your html is structured to make life easier:  `$('div').each( function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('show')){
        
    }
})`

Comment: @JordiCastilla. i want to show content respect to which one of menu has show class. if menu2 has class of show. I could print class for content2 id.

Comment: @Azzah what would you do exactly with the `id` assigned to content afterwards ? if you make that clear, maybe there is a better approach than swiping ids all the time. More explanation please

Comment: @AhmadAssaf wait i going to update my qus. thank you

Comment: @Azzah if you assign same class to `content1` and `menu1` with `class="c1 hide"`, `content2` and `menu2` `class="c2 hide"` you can find easily which `menuN` element changed and then find all elements with `class="cN"` and do what you want with them easier than reconstructing `id`'s...

Comment: @AhmadAssaf i have updated my code with jquery on snippet. can you please correct it.?

Comment: @Azzah check my answer the code snippet

Answer (score 1):

there is a much and better way to do this. You should have some kind of link between both and the menu and content, to do so, i suggest having some `data-attribute`. for example:

```
<!--Menu--> 
<div class="menu" data-target="content1">Menu 1</div>
<div class="menu" data-target="content2">Menu 2</div>
.....
<div class="menu" data-target="content10">Menu 10</div>

<!--Content-->
<table>
<tr><td class="content" id="content0">Menu 1 Content</td></tr>
<tr><td class="content" id="content1">Menu 2 Content</td></tr>

<tr><td class="content" id="content10">Menu 10 Content</td></tr>
</table>
```

then, what you want to do is to see what menu element has the `show` class and show the content with a specific id that corresponds to the `data-target`

```
$('#' + $('.menu').hasClass('show').attr('data-target')).addClass();
```

this will find the element of class menu that has the `show` class, extract the id and put it in a selector for content.

However, i guess when you want to do is when you click on some menu item, you want to show that content, right ? then:

```
$('.menu').on('click', function(){
  var contentID = $(this).data('target');
  $('#' + contentID ).addClass('showContent');
  // or you can even use toggleClass if you want to toggle the behavior
  $('#' + contentID ).toggleClass('showContent');
})
```

```js
    $('.menu').on('click', function(){
      var contentID = $(this).data('target');
      $('#' + contentID ).toggle()
    })
```

```css
.content {display:none}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--Menu--> 
    <div class="menu" data-target="content1">Menu 1</div>
    <div class="menu" data-target="content2">Menu 2</div>
    .....
    <div class="menu" data-target="content10">Menu 10</div>
    
    <!--Content-->
    <table>
    <tr><td class="content" id="content1">Menu 1 Content</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="content" id="content2">Menu 2 Content</td></tr>
    
    <tr><td class="content" id="content10">Menu 10 Content</td></tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
var id = document.getElementsByClassName("show")[0].id;
var menu_number = id.split("menu");
var existing_show_content = document.getElementsByClassName("show-content")[0];

if (existing_show_content) {
    existing_show_content.className = "";
}
document.getElementById("content"+menu_number[1]).parentNode.className = "show-content";
</script>

<!-- language: lang-html -->

<!--Menu--> 
<div id="menu0" class="hide">Menu 1</div>
<div id="menu1" class="show">Menu 2</div>
.....
<div id="menu10" class="hide">Menu 10</div>

<!--Content-->
<table>
<tr><td id="content0">Menu 1 Content</td></tr>
<tr><td id="content1">Menu 2 Content</td></tr>

<tr><td id="content10">Menu 10 Content</td></tr>
</table>

<!-- end snippet -->
```